# mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice: Undefined property

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3

Есть компонент в котором при загрузке изображений имена сохраняются через md5. Есть плагин, который позволяет загружать и сохранять изображения с человекопонятным именем. 
Но при обращении к определенным страницам в логах сервера происходит запись:

... mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Joomla\CMS\Object\CMSObject::$plugins in .../plugins/k2/econa/econa.php

фрагмент кода на который ругается сервер:

```
 public function onK2PrepareContent(&$item, $params, $page = 0)
{
    $plugins = new JRegistry($item->plugins);
    $image = $plugins->get('econafilename');
    if ($image) {
        $filename = JFile::stripExt($image);
        $extension = JFile::getExt($image);
        foreach ($this->properies as $key => $property) {
            $item->$property = JUri::root(true).'/media/k2/items/cache/'.$image.'_'.$this->sizes[$key].'.jpg';
        }

        // K2 content module
        if ($params->get('parsedInModule')) {
            $size = 'image'.$params->get('itemImgSize', 'Small');
            if (isset($item->$size)) {
                $item->image = $item->$size;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как устранить данное предупреждение. Спасибо!